# PHP - Don't Count Users from index.php

Tags: php, counter, visitors

I have a basic online visitors counter. I get it from [here](http://www.phpeasycode.com/visitors/). It works verry well but I have a issue. I use it on online game and I have multiple servers. I use it for server online counter. I did add counter pages to the servers via iframe and it counts very well.

But the problem is, I want to display that numbers on index (index.php) page. But when I use :

```
<?php include("server1.php");?>
```

it counts index page users as well. I don't want this. How can I make it don't count IP's from index.php?

Here, my codes

Counter (server1.php)

```
<?php
$dbfile = "game/database/1.db";  // path to data file
$expire = 100; // average time in seconds to consider someone online before removing from the list

if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
}

if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
}

function CountVisitors() {
    global $dbfile, $expire;
    $cur_ip = getIP();
    $cur_time = time();
    $dbary_new = array();

    $dbary = unserialize(file_get_contents($dbfile));
    if(is_array($dbary)) {
        while(list($user_ip, $user_time) = each($dbary)) {
            if(($user_ip != $cur_ip) && (($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time)) {
                $dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
            }
        }
    }
    $dbary_new[$cur_ip] = $cur_time; // add record for current user

    $fp = fopen($dbfile, "w");
    fputs($fp, serialize($dbary_new));
    fclose($fp);

    $out = sprintf("%03d", count($dbary_new)); // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
    return $out;
}

function getIP() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else $ip = "0";
    return $ip;
}

$visitors_online = '0'+CountVisitors();
?>

<?=$visitors_online;?>
```

Iframe (I use it on server pages)

```
<iframe name="visitors" src="../1.php" width="1" hidden="true" height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

php include (index.php)

```
Server 7 - Online Players:<?php include("7.php");?>
```

Comment: Hi Erin, do you have any variables set which let the server know that the user is logged in??

You could base the function count around that and only count if they have their status as logged in, and not just visiting.

`if($login===true){ $visitors_online = '0'+CountVisitors();}`

Comment: @guyver4mk not really. It's F2P game without registration or login. I have chat and I can check name but it's not "must do" thing for playing game so it would be pretty messy.

Comment: Ah, I see. You could also try basing it on the URL of the server the script is being called on with something like `if(strpos('visitors', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])==false){ # Count Function # }` Just change the string to search for, to a page you want to ignore

Comment: Side note: function getIP() is pretty vulnerable to inject an wrong IP or inject cross site scripting vectors. Dont trust $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] to be safe because an client can change these by spoofing.

Comment: you can check if the current page file is index.php in a conditional statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a server2.php with this code

```
<?php
$dbfile = "game/database/1.db";  // path to data file
$expire = 100;

if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
}

if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
}

function CountVisitors() {
    global $dbfile, $expire;
    $cur_time = time();
    $dbary_new = array();

    $dbary = unserialize(file_get_contents($dbfile));
    if(is_array($dbary)) {
        while(list($user_ip, $user_time) = each($dbary)) {
            if(($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time) {
                $dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
            }
        }
    }

    $out = sprintf("%03d", count($dbary_new)); // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
    return $out;
}

$visitors_online = '0'+CountVisitors();
?>

<?=$visitors_online;?>
```

and use it like server1.php

Comment: This is pretty much best solution. I have 7 servers but I guess there is no option. Thanks!